# Returning a NSMutableURLRequest with a url that contains quotes

Tags: nsstring, nsurl

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/myzip?\"30339\"";
NSLog(@"urlstring: %@", urlString);
// RETURNS=> urlstring: http://example.com/myzip?"30339"
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSLog(@"request: %@", request);
// RETURNS=> request: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x8f54480> { URL: (null) }
```

I am unable to complete a NSMutableURLRequest if my URL has quotes inside of it. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

`"` is not a legal character for use in URLs, and must be escaped instead (as `%22`), like so:

```
http://example.com/myzip?%2230339%22
```